# Testing location services on device

Tags: ios, xcode, location, core-location

I am trying to test background location changing using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`
In the simulator, I can enable Freeway Drive mode and I get regular calls to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` which is great.=, the problem is debugging when the app is terminated and it's meant to be woken up.
I have changed the RUN scheme to "Wait for my.app to launch" and again this works good as the debugger waits for the app to become active. The downside is, I can't view any NSLogs and the simulator doesn't have a way to view the Device Logs.
So I moved over to device as I thought at least I can view the Device Logs, however the device doesn't have a Freeway Drive mode.
I've created a .gpx file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode"> 
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030237"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030337"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030437"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.030537"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.031437"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.031537"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.031437"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.032537"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.032437"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="37.331705" lon="-122.032537"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="36.331705" lon="-122.030437"></wpt>
    <wpt lat="36.331705" lon="-122.030537"></wpt>
</gpx>
```

And in the RUN scheme set it as the default location.
I can see that the coordinates of the device are changing as I fly through the default maps app, however none of the locationManager delegate methods are being called like they where in the simulator.

Any help appreciated on how I can test this.

Thanks

Comment: From xCode Window->Organizer->Device->Console should give you NSLog preview from all running apps on device. Is this helpful for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator. Or modify it to better fill your needs(my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930776/2082172))

**Edit**

(I'm one of the authors) https://github.com/Azoft/FakeGPSUtility - can be helpful too.