# How to simulate significant Location update in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, location

is there any means to check significant location change in simulator instead of GPS updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator. Or modify it to better fill your needs.

**Edit**

(I'm one of the authors:) https://github.com/Azoft/FakeGPSUtility - this project can be helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using the simulator's 'Free Drive' option.

Once you have your code setup for monitoring significant location updates, do the following:

1. Select your simulator
2. Select Debug -> Location -> Free Drive
3. Add a breakpoint to CLLocationManager's `didUpdateLocations` delegate method to catch updates

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080178/1048331

Answer (score 1):

Select `iPhone Simulator`--> Select `Debug` from `menu` ---> `set Location`.
You can also give custom location by filling `longitude` and `latitude` values.

Comment: This won't simulate a significant-change event.